# How to rename files in a folder based on a list?

Tags: python

I have a folder with about 30 images saved as '0001', '0002' etc... so on and forth and I have filenames that I want to rename them with in a list. I have written some code but am currently getting the error

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '0001.jpg' -> 'Filename1'

```
 import os

directory = os.fsencode('Folder')
new_filenames = ['Filename1','Filename2'.....]
    
for index, file in enumerate(os.listdir(directory)):
     old_filename = os.fsdecode(file)
      os.rename(old_filename, new_filenames[index])
```

Where do I go from here?

Comment: can you try with `new_filenames = ['Filename1.jpg','Filename2.jpg'.....]`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import os

directory = os.fsencode('Folder')
new_filenames = ['Filename1.jpg','Filename2.jpg'.....]
    
for index, file in enumerate(os.listdir(directory)):
    old_filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    os.rename(old_filename, new_filenames[index])
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)

Replace **THE_NAME_OF_THE_FOLDER_TO_COPY_FROM** with the folder name **if** it is already in your working directory or gives the full **path** to the folder of the images.

```
import glob

path= "THE_NAME_OF_THE_FOLDER_TO_COPY_FROM"
images = glob.glob(path + "*.jpg")
print(images)
```

This is an example path on my windows 10 I've just tested it.

> ```
> path = "C:/Users/ghaith/Desktop/test/"
> ```

if you print them, you will see that you get a list with each image name sth like **[FOLDER_NAME/IMAGE_NAME.png, ....]**

Then, make use of this list to loop over all images and change their name respectively with [replace](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_replace.asp).

So as I've understood that you want to rename and remove the **000** in each image, Right?

```
for index, img in enumerate(images):
    os.rename(img, img.replace('000', ''))
```

or you can write it by using **list comprehension** with one line.

```
[os.rename(img, img.replace('000', '')) for img in images]
```